# awk to search file using value from another file in different field

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to search `f2` `$8` for the value from `f1` `$7`. If the value matches in `f2` then `$1-$4`, that value and `$7` are printed, but if the value is not found,
then `Not found` is printed. Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS="\t"} 
   NR==FNR {a[$1]=$7;next} 
   $1 in a {v=a[$8]; print $1,$2,$3,$4,v,$7, "Not found"}' f1 f2
```

**f1**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    1013490 C   G   NM_005101.3 c.-84C>G    ISG15   NM_005101
chr1    1013541 T   C   NM_005101.3 c.-33T>C    ISG15   NM_005101
chr1    1022492 T   G   NM_198576.3 c.463+30T>G AGRN    NM_198576
chr1    1022515 A   C   NM_198576.3 c.463+53A>C AGRN    NM_198576
```

**f2**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    1013855 G   A   NM_005101.4 c.4-129G>A  NM_005101   ISG15
chr1    1014274 A   G   NM_005101.4 c.294A>G    NM_005101   ISG15
chr1    1014545 C   T   NM_005101.4 c.*5C>T NM_005101   ISG15
chr1    1022492 T   G   NM_198576.4 c.463+30T>G NM_198576   AGRN
chr1    1022515 A   C   NM_198576.4 c.463+53A>CNM_198576    AGRN
chr1    1022587 T   TTGTAGTCTGACCTGTGGTCTGAC    NM_198576.4 c.463+128_463+129insAGTCTGACCTGTGGTCTGACTGT NM_198576   AGRN
chr1    2604062 A   C   NM_033467.4 c.951+85T>G NM_033467   MMEL1
chr1    2604065 A   C   NM_033467.4 c.951+82T>G NM_033467   MMEL1
```

**desired**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    1013855 G   A   ISG15   NM_005101
chr1    1014274 A   G   ISG15   NM_005101
chr1    1014545 C   T   ISG15   NM_005101
chr1    1022492 T   G   AGRN    NM_198576
chr1    1022515 A   C   AGRN    NM_198576
chr1    1022587 T   TTGTAGTCTGACCTGTGGTCTGAC    AGRN    NM_198576
chr1    2604062 A   C   MMEL1   Not Found
chr1    2604065 A   C   MMEL1   Not found
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo that missed a tab character in row with `1022515` before `NM_198576` in `f2`

Comment: Add comment explaining what steps you have taken so far and what problem you are trying to overcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
NR == FNR {
   a[$7]
   next
}
{
   print $1,$2,$3,$4,$8,($8 in a ? $7 : "Not Found")
}' f1 f2

chr1    1013855 G   A   ISG15   NM_005101
chr1    1014274 A   G   ISG15   NM_005101
chr1    1014545 C   T   ISG15   NM_005101
chr1    1022492 T   G   AGRN    NM_198576
chr1    1022515 A   C   AGRN    NM_198576
chr1    1022587 T   TTGTAGTCTGACCTGTGGTCTGAC    AGRN    NM_198576
chr1    2604062 A   C   MMEL1   Not Found
chr1    2604065 A   C   MMEL1   Not Found
```